# datatable not recognised outside of class?

Tags: c#

I have the following code which write the contents of my datagrid to a text file:

```
        string FSYear = "FS_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_Grids";

        string sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT [ProductCode] FROM " + FSYear;
        DataTable Temp = SqlConnect(sql2);

        //create txt file of codes
        string path = @"C:\Users\user\Temp\Images.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
        }

        //Empty text file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);

        //use results from query
        List1.Items.Add("Writing " + Temp.Rows.Count + " lines...");
        foreach (DataRow row in Temp.Rows)
        {
            string productCode = row["ProductCode"].ToString();
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine(productCode);


                }

            }
        }
        List1.Items.Add("Finished");
```

What I would like it to do is only write if the "ProductCode" is a number, and then for the count of these to be reflected in Temp.Rows.Count.

Is this something that is possible? And if so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to check if you have a number, you can do something like this:

```
  int result;
      if (int.TryParse(productCode, out result))
     { 
     //Number , count?
     }
    else
     {
    // Not number
     }
```

Now, in your temp DataTable, you have all the values, why not just count when it is a number?